# can nunit 2.6 run with resharper 6.1.1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, resharper

Is there a way to upgrade resharper 6.1.1 to use nunit 2.6 in the test browser or generally ?
`NUnit` 2.6 supports the new `ActionAttribute`.
i need it in order to run the database creation functionality.

any way to do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it cannot.

This is from one of R# developers:

> mar-05-2012
>
> Re: Exception running NUnit 2.6 tests
> NUnit 2.6 was released just a few days ago and is not yet supported in ReSharper 6.1.1 because it was released earlier.
> We are working on NUnit 2.6 support and it will be available in future releases.

Blogged in: [Exception running NUnit 2.6 tests](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5453470?tstart=0)